# Using jQuery/PHP/mySQL to update database and display new result

Tags: jquery

Hi all I am fairly new to programming. I have been teaching myself php and css and is trying to combine that with some jQuery.

I have a site with a list of items that I want to allow the user to vote up. (www.blueskycouncil.com you can log in with stack/this)

currently I am updating the database by sending this:

```
<a href=\"idea_karma.php?pagetype=index&karmatype=ideaspace&id={$row['id']}&sort_id=$sort_id\">
```

to idea_karma.php, check if the user has already voted on it and if not update the database.

This works fine (noob code aside)

Now I want to do it with jQuery instead so that I only update the point rather than the entire page.

Two two of the variables are dynamic (id and sort_id), the specific value get's assigned in a loop.

My question is how to I approach this?

I have tried a couple of things but I can't seem to get them to work.

This is the sript

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function get() { 
$.get('idea_karma.php', {"pagetype": index, "karmatype": ideaspace, "id": id, "sort_id":   sortid},

function (output) {
    $('#karma').html(output).show();
    }};

}
```

This is where I do the call to the script

```
<div class=\"karma-btn\">
<a href=\"idea_karma.php?pagetype=index&karmatype=ideaspace&id= {$row['id']}&sort_id=$sort_id\" onClick=\"get();\">
<img src=\"images/btn_lrg_karma.png\" alt=\"Alternative text\">
<span class=\"voted\"><div id="karma">{$row['karma']</div>}</span></a>                                                      </div>
```

Comment: Show us what you tried. Post some code.

Comment: Bear in mind that using JavaScript to show the actions will still require a php (or other server-side) intermediary to effect the changes.

Comment: there are a few problems... for one, the variables `id` and `sortid` do not exist in your `get()` function. Also, `index` and `ideaspace` are strings, you the need quotes. See my example below...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is change that link so that it will call a javascript function with the proper parameters when it is clicked. The javascript function will do the AJAX, and look something like this:

```
function updateKarma(id, sortId){
  $.post("idea_karma.php", 
  {pagetype: "index", karmatype: "ideaspace", id: id, sort_id: sortId}, 
  function(){
    //in here you can do you stuff when the call returns
    alert("karma updated");
  });
}
```

Then, your link code will look like:

```
<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" onclick=\"updateKarma('{$row['id']}', '$sort_id')\">
```

I think this is what you're after?

Comment: I became late in providing same solution as yours. :)

Comment: The slashes are because he had slashes in the example... I'm assuming that link is inside a php string enclosed with double quotes... so the literal double quotes need to be escaped.

Comment: @Alpesh it's amazing how quickly answers happen on SO. I saw this question with zero responses and thought I could answer it...while I'm typing my answer 3 other answers appear and the question is marked as solved before I finish typing. Amazing.

Comment: @Jonathan Mayhak: so true. But this is the actual advantage of stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign an onclick function to the anchor as below -

```
<a href="#nodo" onclick="update_vote('<?=$row['id']?>','<?=$sort_id?>')">vote</a>
```

Then you can write a function below in your js file -

```
function update_vote(id,sort_id){


//Now you can call the url you were calling through the of the jquery.

// You can update spection section in page in the `sucess` callback function of ajax.

}
```

Detailed documentation of ajax is available at - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 2):

The following is the basic idea to get you going with ajax:

```
function doKarma(id, sort_id) {
    var keyValue = {
        'method' : 'doKarma',
        'pageType' : 'index',
        'karmaType' : 'ideaspace',
        'id' : id,
        'sort_id' : sort_id
    };    
    $.post('/idea_karma.php', keyValue, function(xml) {
        var stat = $(xml).find('rsp').attr('stat');
        // stat will represent whether your api call failed or was a success
        if (stat === 'ok') {
            // update your counter
            alert('success');
        }
        else {
            // user has already voted or something went wrong
            alert('failed');
        }
    },'xml');
}
```

This is an example of your idea_karma.php page

```
<?php

if ($_POST['method'] == 'doKarma') {
    //perform update of karma

    header("Content-type: text/xml");
    // if success
    echo '<rsp stat=\"ok\"></rsp>';
    // else echo '<rsp stat=\"error\"></rsp>';
}

?>
```

Comment: thnx. Someone beat you to the "correct" answer but all answers are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the jQuery API for [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), [Get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), [Post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).  If you need specific help with code you already wrote, I would recommend posting it and we can help you troubleshoot.